# How steep is the learning curve in Magic: The Gathering: Duels of the Planewalkers?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers

I am completely new to the Magic: The Gathering world, but am an old D&D player and the like. How steep is the learning curve, and how does it compare to the physical (paper) version?

How well does it play on PC (I have a Compaq Presario CQ41 Laptop)?

How long is the single-player campaign?

Comment: I tweaked your question a little to avoid it being summarily closed as being subjective.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The learning curve to DOTP is simple as it highlights cards that are usuable & basically completes any steps that are required to cast spells for you (i.e. tapping mana). It is very simple compared to the paper version or even MTG Online as the closest thing to deck building is the ability to add certain cards to decks, instead of having a large pool of cards to choose from & building decks from scratch.

All-in-all a fun game, but definately aimed at newer players. Give the 5-minute tutorial a run through & you'll be fine.

The graphics aren't too intense, & you shouldn't have a problem with the laptop being able to run it.

**Edit:** I looked at your original question - Yes, the single campaign is fun as the opponents decks do actually get harder as you play along. If you're a completionist, the single player campaign will be where you'll focus most of your time too.

Comment: +1 for "It is very simple compared to the paper version or even MTG Online" MTG: DOTP is just a stripped down version of the real game. If @rODRIGO-o planning to really get into Magic the gathering, and want a computer version - buy magic the gathering online.

Comment: Thanks @Wipqozn but the point is I don't really have much online time.

Comment: Planeswalkers also has the advantage of largely removing the collectable / money sink element if you're not keen on that part of the game.

Comment: @Christi - Good point, especially the money sink. However, the collectible element of the game is a factor I do like & DOTP has almost none of it.